# Can't import d3.hexbin from d3 in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I have a similar issue to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384029/cannot-import-d3-tip-or-d3-hexbin-into-react-component) post.
Unfortunately the solution there has not worked for me.
How can I use d3.hexbin inside a react component?
I've included it in the dependencies and installed it.

```
"dependencies": {
"d3": "^7.3.0",
"d3-hexbin": "^0.2.2"
```

}

I imported d3 originally just like this:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Other than hexbin I can use most modules and was able to do scatter and bar charts so far.
I am fairly new to this, and am sorry if I'm missing something obvious, please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Typescript, first make sure you have installed `@types/d3-hexbin` to your devDependencies.

Did you try:

```
import * as d3 from ‘d3-hexbin’

const hexbin = d3.hexbin
```

If you already have a d3 instance, you can rename the import like:

```
import * as d3Hexbin from 'd3-hexbin'

const {hexbin} = d3Hexbin
```

After importing the library, here is how to destructure and rename in one line:

```
const {hexbin: d3HB} = d3Hexbin
```

Here's [a working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-kapitsa-o0mpen?file=/src/index.ts:0-56)

Comment: I have the former, I'll try the latter now. Thanks, will report back.

Comment: sorry, earlier I was silly and copied without adjusting.
Error: Can't resolve 'd3-hexbin' this is what I get now.

Comment: Did it do the trick? If so, can you please accept my answer? If not, what’s happening now?

Comment: Hi @Kraken no I get the Can't resolve d3-hexbin error I mentioned above. Sorry

Comment: If you're using Typescript, make sure you have installed `@types/d3-hexbin` first to your devDependencies.

Comment: Not sure what else to offer. I updated my answer, which you can see working in the linked sandbox. Maybe try a quick sanity check. If you're using VS Code, restart the typescript compiler. You can do this via the command palette or simply be restarting your editor.

Comment: thank you very much, sorry for the late reply, I am an early riser and was in bed already. I tried it out and it was the @types/d3-hexbin that was missing. Thank you so much!
so now everytime I use it I have to access it with d3HB.hexbin()
Could I ask why this is?

Comment: Essentially, hexbin is a member of the d3-hexbin library. You can use the second example to get rid of the `d3.` prefix. I’ll even add an update so you can see how to destructure and rename in one line. I’m glad you’re unstuck. Cheers!

Comment: Happy to help. Enjoy